# Отображение MapPolyline на карте QML. C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

По заданию необходимо отобразить карту на экране и рисовать на ней линии. Пробую сделать вот так:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGeoPath>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QTimer>

class PathController: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QGeoPath geopath READ geoPath WRITE setGeoPath NOTIFY geopathChanged)
public:
    PathController(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

    QGeoPath geoPath() const {
        return mGeoPath;
    }

    void setGeoPath(const QGeoPath &geoPath) {
        if(geoPath != mGeoPath) {
            mGeoPath = geoPath;
            emit geopathChanged();
        }
    }

signals:
    void geopathChanged();

private:
    QGeoPath mGeoPath;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QGeoPath path;
    path.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(55.006355, 92.860984));
    path.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(55.1, 93));
    path.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.1, 92.777));

    PathController controller;
    controller.setGeoPath(path);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("pathController", &controller);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Plugin {
        id: osmMapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmMapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)
        zoomLevel: 10

        MapPolyline {
            id: pl
            line.width: 3
            line.color: 'red'
        }
    }

    Connections{
        target: pathController
        onGeopathChanged: {
            var lines = []
            for(var i=0; i < pathController.geopath.size(); i++){
                lines[i] = pathController.geopath.coordinateAt(i)
            }
            pl.path = lines
        }
    }
}
```

Однако получаю пустую карту. Линии не появляются. Вопрос - каким образом отрендеривать линии? Они ведь существуют, просто как бы "невидимы".

[image: Должен быть треугольник на полэкрана]

Comment: Может следует вызвать [`setPath`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtlocation-mappolyline.html#setPath-method), а не поле присваивать?

Comment: @VTT нет, проблема не в этом. Оператор '=' переопределён. Если вызвать `printf("%s", controller.geoPath().toString().toUtf8().constData());`, то выведется то, что я только что вводил.